# How to tie (connect) to values in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I am newbie in programming and I need some help.
I have table (clubs) in DB with teams names and their id.
Next I want to create match in table "matches" in new table named "matches".

How can I tie team's id from "clubs" with teams (home&away)in table matches. I need that id in next actions.

I thought about foreing key, but I cant us it.

Thanks in advance for ur help

Comment: Why can't you use foreign keys?

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a substitute for basic education. What you want is a _join_. Go back to your SQL tutorials and read about this.

Comment: Please find a SQL tutorial (you can  do so via Google or Bing). A `JOIN` is a very basic operation, and you'll need to learn about it and some other things before you can do anything useful with a DB at all. The tutorial will save you a lot of effort in the future. (StackOverflow is not a tutorial site, I'm afraid.) Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regardless of if the two tables are linked via. a foreign key relationship (although it is good practice to do so) when selecting  you can still use a `JOIN` to connect the two tables. Since you have both a home and away team you need to join the clubs table twice, once for each team.

```
SELECT m.*, ch.name AS homeClub
FROM matches m
INNER JOIN clubs ch
ON ch.id = matches.home_id
```

This query will get the match and the home club name, I leave it to you to figure out how to get the away club's name.

Read http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html for more information on using joins.

Comment: tx. I will try it. I like to do it myself, to think and to learn. Thanks for pointing direction.